# The labels are displayed but data is not displayed

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I'm developing code to get the data from remote Ajax, but am unable to display  the data needed.

However the label's name is correctly displayed.

From remote, in PHP i've this:

```
for ( $i = $start; $i <= $end; $i = $i + 86400 ) {
    $SQDate     = date( 'Y-m-d', $i ); 
    $PMS_ci     = $this->getPMS_ci_status($SQDate);
    $PMS_co     = $this->getPMS_co_status($SQDate);
    if($PMS_ci["sum"] == "")
        $PMS_ci["sum"] = "0";
    if($PMS_co["sum"] == "")
        $PMS_co["sum"] = "0";
    $arrival[]  = $PMS_ci["sum"];
    $departure[]= $PMS_co["sum"];
}
$data[]     = array("name" => "Arrival", "data" => join($arrival,","));
$data[]     = array("name" => "Departure", "data" => join($departure,","));

return JSON_encode($data);
```

Side Javascript:

```
retour = JSON.parse(data.message);
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline'
        },
    .../...
    ,
    series: [{name: retour[0].name ,data: retour[0].data},
             {name: retour[1].name, data: retour[1].data}],
    navigation: {
    .../...
```

The content of data returns this:

```
[
    {
        "name":"Arrival",
        "data":"[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]"
    },
    {
        "name":"Departure",
        "data":"[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]"
    }
]
```

In all cases, the needed data is not displayed, but the names are displayed correctly.

I don't know why.I read some threads here without success. What should be done to make sure the data is displayed along with the labels?

Comment: Can you provide your html for that? And what is `data.message`?

Answer (score 0):

**From**

```
$data[]     = array("name" => "Arrival", "data" => join($arrival,","));
                                                   ^
                                            No need of join, json_encode
                                            takes care of it
```

**To**

```
$data[]     = array("name" => "Arrival", "data" => $arrival);
```

And your json becomes

**From**

```
[{"name":"Arrival","data":"[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]"},{"name":"Departure","data":"[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]"}]
                          ^
                         Should be array not string
```

**To**

```
[{"name":"Arrival","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"Departure","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}]
```

And you can rewrite your code like below

```
for ( $i = $start; $i <= $end; $i = $i + 86400 ) 
    {
          $SQDate     = date( 'Y-m-d', $i ); 
          $PMS_ci     = $this->getPMS_ci_status($SQDate);
          $PMS_co     = $this->getPMS_co_status($SQDate);

          $arrival[]  =  $PMS_ci["sum"]+0;
          $departure[]= $PMS_co["sum"]+0;
    }

        $data[]     = array("name" => "Arrival", "data" =>$arrival);
        $data[]     = array("name" => "Departure", "data" => $departure);

        // Return to caller (since PHP 5.3.3)
        // and from caller do echo  
        return json_encode($data,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: The changes give : 
"[{"name":"Arrival","data":["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","2","3","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]},{"name":"Departure","data":["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","2","3","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]}]"

Comment: But now way. nothing to display.

Comment: @Danard: I just edited, try with `return json_encode($data,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);`

Comment: Found:       $arrival[]  = intval($PMS_ci["sum"]);
      $departure[]= intval($PMS_co["sum"]);

Comment: Thanks a lot sir :)

Comment: @Danard: you can do use `intval`, `(int)$PMS_ci["sum"]` or `$PMS_ci["sum"]+0` for converting

Comment: @Danard: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work